# what's the mechanism of `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` function to control training and evaluation period?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, object-detection-api

When I trained a SSD object detection model 20K steps using [TensorFlow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md), I found that the training time varies:
It was training fast on the first 10 minutes, and around 500 steps were performed (i.e. 0.83 steps/seconds). Then it slowed down and took about 40~50 minutes to perform single training step, evaluate the model on the evaluation dataset and save the checkpoint on disk. So I interrupted the training after few steps and continued by restoring the training.
Every time, it training fast on the first 10 minutes and then slowed down sharply as the figures showed. 
[image: global_step]
[image: saved checkpoints]
The model's training are implemented by [TensorFlow's Estimator API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate) `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate()`
Can anyone explain how it works? How the estimator controls the training and evaluation period? I do not want to evaluate the model for every step!

Comment: TensorFlow version: 1.11.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [EvalSpec](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EvalSpec) and [TrainSpec](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/TrainSpec) there is an argument throttle_secs, which is responsible for deciding when evaluation is called. Refer to [this heated discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13895#issuecomment-374796583), which has many details about Estimator methods! Controlling this would be the option to control train and eval cycles. Also in general, train_and_evaluate will work by building a graph of the the training and evaluation operation. The training graph is created only once, but evaluation graph is recreated every time you need to evaluate. This means that it will load the checkpoint that was created during training, which maybe one reason why this is taking so long! Maybe [InMemoryEvaluationHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.9/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/InMemoryEvaluatorHook) that is mentioned in that discussion can help you out, since it does not reload the checkpoint everytime evaluation is called.

Comment: Yes, there is a `throttle_secs` argument for `tf.estimator.EvalSpec()` and its default value is `600`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As the `tf.estimator.EvalSpec()` said, there are two arguments for this function to control evluation cycles, `start_delay_secs` and `throttle_secs`. So I think the first evaluation is performed at `start_delay_secs` seconds after I start the training, and then the following evaluations are performed every `throttle_secs`  seconds. Am I right?

Comment: @yann that is right! In the generic case, evaluate is actually called every time there is a checkpoint happening. Throttle_secs actually lets you checkpoint more but  evaluate less by specifying the number of seconds to wait between two evaluations. There are some confusions regarding local and distributed training and changing evaluation frequency with respect to checkpoint frequency though. You would need to watch out for behavior that doesn't conform that way. I think I had bookmarked a github issue about that. Let me see if I can find it.

Comment: @yann [this is the issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17650) I was referring to.

Comment: Yeah, the issue provides some information, but it seems not a final conclusion.

Comment: @yann if you look at the [run_on_local](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py#L667) function thats referenced in the [last comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17650#issuecomment-417752435) before they close the issue, this seems to be the last major upgrade. I think this along with throttle_secs would ultimately be the deciders for the frequency. There doesnt seem to be any further issues raised in this regard.

Comment: Yes. The evaluation frequency is determined by the saving frequency. If the model is saved after every step (not epoch), the evaluation on the whole dataset is slowing down the training...